# iOS 6 - Keyboard does not show even the UIView is still first responder

Tags: ios, ios6

I have an `UIView` work like a textEditor with can become first responder to show keyboard. When my `UIView` with keyboard is showing, I press home button to put app to background and open other app, open a file to my app. The problem is the keyboard is not automatically shown after the modal `viewController` is dismissed.

I have a check and see: the `isFirstResponder` of my `UIView` is YES. But the keyboard is still not available. At that time my application have 2 windows, but the second window does not contains keyboard as usual.

It's weird. Anyone have this problem like me ?

Note that this issue is only on iOS 6.0.

Comment: I am very confused. How does you app have two windows? What does "open a file to my app" mean? I think you need to clarify your question.

Comment: I mean staying on app A and open-in a file to app B. App B is my App which can handle the file which transfered from app A.